# Implementing a variable width in Tailwind CSS/NativeWind

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css

I am trying to use a variable to create a progress bar by using two views and setting the width equal to a percentage of the parent view. I would like to do this using Tailwind's utility classes.

```js
    <View className='w-full h-10 bg-blue-500'>
        <View className={`w-[${percentage}] h-10 bg-blue-300`}/> // this uses back ticks, which works for px values, but not percentage
    <View/>
```

I have tried adding % sign everywhere in the `className`, with no success. Obviously, it works if I use the `style` attribute, but ideally I would only use the `className` attribute.

Comment: Tailwind cannot detect dynamic classes. You'll want to use static classes instead https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names. Use the style property to apply the width in your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, Tailwind does not generate classes at runtime. To achieve this with classes either requires Tailwind to make every single possible class that's a percentage (only feasible if `percentage` is an integer), but that bloats your styles, or for there to be something at runtime, constantly scanning each element for tailwind-like classes.

The best option, especially since you're doing such a simple property, is to use the `style` attribute.